# Loading data from Retrofit issue: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, retrofit

First, the JSON I'm getting from the server:

```
{
"actor": [
    {
        "uid": "/actor-12461615214214348149",
        "subtype": "some type",
        "location": {
            "lat": 38.931,
            "lng": -77.21
        },
        "prop1": 100,
        "prop2": 1,
        "prop3": 20,
        "prop4": 80
    },
    {
        "uid": "/actor-13893903348679219933",
        "subtype": "some type",
        "location": {
            "lat": 38.93,
            "lng": -77.21
        },
        "prop1": 100,
        "prop2": 1,
        "prop3": 20,
        "prop4": 80
    },
    {
        "uid": "/actor-13809263303067864337",
        "subtype": "some type",
        "location": {
            "lat": 38.93,
            "lng": -77.21
        },
        "prop1": 100,
        "prop2": 1,
        "prop3": 20,
        "prop4": 80
    }        
  ]
}
```

And the POJO I wanted to load from it:

```
public class Actor {

private String uid;
private String subtype;
private Location loc;
private int prop1;
private int prop2;
private String prop3;
private String prop4;

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getSubtype() {
    return subtype;
}

public void setSubtype(String subtype) {
    this.subtype = subtype;
}

public Location getLoc() {
    return loc;
}

public void setLoc(Location loc) {
    this.loc = loc;
}

public int getProp1() {
    return prop1;
}

public void setProp1(int prop1) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
}

public int getProp2() {
    return prop2;
}

public void setProp2(int prop2) {
    this.prop2 = prop2;
}

public String getProp3() {
    return prop3;
}

public void setPower(String prop3) {
    this.prop3 = prop3;
}

public String getProp4() {
    return prop4;
}

public void setProp4(String prop4) {
    this.prop4 = prop4;
}


public class Location{
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }
    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

  }
}
```

The web service invocation I've specified is looking for an Actor[] response.

After all this, I'm seeing RetroFit's IllegalStateException:  Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

I've reviewed the other RetroFit errors posted here and they most frequently appear to be cases of people trying to load arrays when the data they are getting is a single object.  Alternatively the inverse is cases where people are getting an array of objects and trying to load it into a single pojo.

In my case, though, it appears to me like I've got a good match between the array I'm trying to load and the array of simple objects coming in JSON format.

I'm clearly missing something....another pair of eyes pls?

Comment: The response isn't an array of Actors, it's an object containing an array of Actors.

Comment: You should post your Retrofit interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to solve the issue:

1- If you have access to your the server to change the service, make it to provide responses like:

```
[
{
    "uid": "/actor-12461615214214348149",
    "subtype": "some type",
    "location": {
        "lat": 38.931,
        "lng": -77.21
    },
    "prop1": 100,
    "prop2": 1,
    "prop3": 20,
    "prop4": 80
},
{
    "uid": "/actor-13893903348679219933",
    "subtype": "some type",
    "location": {
        "lat": 38.93,
        "lng": -77.21
    },
    "prop1": 100,
    "prop2": 1,
    "prop3": 20,
    "prop4": 80
}]
```

2- If you can't change the values from the server, create a wrapper POJO with the actor list and make retrofit to provide this as a callback.

```
public class ActorWrapper {
    private List<Actor> actor;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Comment: I went with the wrapper approach.  No errors now, but it's also not parsing a single thing.  All elements in the Actor list are null.

Comment: Did you named it actor in the wrapper class?